# Trying to save multiple EditText values and then display them with Try and Catch

Tags: android

I need to be able to display multiple saved entries from `EditText` fields that are saved to the internal storage of the device. I already have 3 different `EditText` fields to display on the `TextView` fields when data is entered. Now I need new entries to display without replacing the old entries displayed. Should I replace the *temp* in *txType.setText(temp)* with something else? Below is my code.....

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText etType, etMiles, etDate;
Button btAdd;
TextView txType, txMiles, txDate;

String dataType, dataMiles, dataDate;
private String fileType = "myTypeData";
private String fileMiles = "myMilesData";
private String fileDate = "myDateData";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    etType=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etType);
    etMiles=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etMiles);
    etDate=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etDate);

    txType=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txType);
    txMiles=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txMiles);
    txDate=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txDate);

    btAdd=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btAdd);
    btAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dataType=etType.getText().toString();
            try {
                FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput(fileType,MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                fOut.write(dataType.getBytes());
                fOut.close();

            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try{
                FileInputStream fin = openFileInput(fileType);
                int c;
                String temp="";

                while( (c = fin.read()) != -1){
                    temp = temp + Character.toString((char)c);
                }
                txType.setText(temp);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
            }

            dataMiles=etMiles.getText().toString();
            try {
                FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput(fileMiles,MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                fOut.write(dataMiles.getBytes());
                fOut.close();

            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try{
                FileInputStream fin = openFileInput(fileMiles);
                int c;
                String temp="";

                while( (c = fin.read()) != -1){
                    temp = temp + Character.toString((char)c);
                }
                txMiles.setText(temp);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
            }

            dataDate=etDate.getText().toString();
            try {
                FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput(fileDate,MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                fOut.write(dataDate.getBytes());
                fOut.close();

            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try{
                FileInputStream fin = openFileInput(fileDate);
                int c;
                String temp="";

                while( (c = fin.read()) != -1){
                    temp = temp + Character.toString((char)c);
                }
                txDate.setText(temp);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Workout Saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
            catch(Exception e){
              }

          }
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: This question doesn't concern the functionality of `try catch`. IMHO if you want different entries than the ones already saved then using `EditText` and `TextView` doesn't make much sense. Use a `ListView` it will contain your previous entries as well as you can new ones.

Comment: Crap...I did not think of that. Thanks.

Comment: so you want the previous text added to the new one and display it . right ?

Comment: yes, as Sharp Edge stated, I should try a ListView but right now I am having no luck.

Comment: You want new `textView` for the new value or you want to concatenate your new text to the old  text in textView? Your question is quite unclear